# SSL Offloading with Application Request Routing - How can I make application aware of the secure connection?

Tags: asp.net, https, web-farm-framework

Is there anything I can do to make my application aware that arr is doing SSL offloading?

I want to implement arr with offloading in my current environment but our application currently makes the decision to redirect http to https depending on a setting in our database.

I'd like to continue to manage the redirect from happening or not from my db setting but during testing I see all requests as http and end up in a redirect loop.

How would i force the HTTPS server variable to "on" on the back end servers when the front end of the arr is secure.

thank you for any help/recommended workarounds.
-Danny